# Running the Iphone simulator to run an app from the command line

Tags: iphone, ruby

I currently am using Ruby and want to run the iphone simulator to run a particular program that one of our developers built.

Has anyone tried running an iphone simulator to run a particular program.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [ios-sim](https://github.com/Fingertips/ios-sim) project on GitHub.

It does exactly what you are looking for but is written in Objective-C. However, if you are familiar with Objective-C (*and I'm assuming you are since you're talking about iOS apps*) then it should be pretty trivial to port if it's essential you need to use Ruby. Otherwise you could just use as is.